# ECharts show all values with percent sign

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

What is the best way to add percent sign?

This could be doable using:

```
tooltip : {
    trigger: 'item',
    formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"
}
```

But that is quite annoying when there are multiple categories and values or when the number varies.

Answer (score 1):

`tooltip.formatter` also can be a function. 
Using this, you have full control what and if it should be displayed.

Example:

```
function __handleTooltip(seriesConfiguration) {
    // Your code here    
    // return undefined, if you don't want to show a tooltip
    // return a string, if you want to show a tooltip
}
```

`seriesConfiguration` looks somewhat like that:

```
// This is a SCATTER-Entry
// But line/bar is just similar, it just has different "data" and "value".
{
  "componentType": "series",
  "componentSubType": "scatter",
  "seriesType": "scatter",
  "seriesIndex": 0,
  "seriesName": "Daten",
  "name": "",
  "dataIndex": 9,
  "data": [
    748,
    2206,
    2954,
    "999999999",
    "Some other Value",
    ""
  ],
  "value": [
    748,
    2206,
    2954,
    "999999999",
    "Some other Value",
    ""
  ],
  "color": "rgba(79,142,206,1)",
  "$vars": [
    "seriesName",
    "name",
    "value"
  ]
}
```

Just use console.log to print the object, the rest should be straightforward.